# Has anyone used admobs and GooglePlayServices together in Unity recently?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, google-play-services

I am having so much trouble with unity at the moment, when I try and make a game using admobs and GooglePlayServices together I get numerous different errors, they vary from Repackaging resources error, unable to convert dex formats (from which I understand means I have duplicate files) merging of manifests.
I have seen recently that with the new version of the SDK there is no libProject folder which I understand you need to use inside your project to get it to work, I also had trouble using the latest GooglePlayServices that I got from the SDK and had to downgrade.
Basically what I'm asking is what steps did you take? I can't find anything up to date to help me, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hello, to solve this issue make sure that you are using the same "targetsdk"  (in the manifests) and check your support v4 file (it may be duplicated).

Comment: it is incredibly difficult to get GPS working.  in practice, for any paid/professional jobs everyone uses the Prime31 plugin.  it's still a hassle but at least you "can get it to work".  regarding admobs if you can get it to work, you're the first ever  :)  really, just "forget it" - do you need to add these things that much?  it's tough.  :O